# How to solve the below Dynamic Programming question

Tags: data-structures, dynamic-programming

Recently I have taken a coding challenge on DP and DS. Below is a question where I was struck (I am just framing the question from my memory)

There are n towers each of different height. Each tower is separated by unit distance. Find the maximum length of a rope to be tied between two towers. Length of the rope can be calculated as : sum of absolute difference between tower heights and distance between the towers.

As a beginner in programming, I used two nested for loops and calculated the rope length between each pair of towers and stored the maximum length every time. But when I ran the program, I got time out error(obviously TC will be n^2). This might be an easy one to many of you folks but as a beginner I am still looking for a logic that can reduce the Time complexity. Please let me know the logic or code in python.

Thank you very much in advance. Cheers!!!

Comment: Are the towers aligned, all 1 unit distance apart from the next, and the rope connects the 1st tower head to the next one, until it has reached the last tower? That is, you need to order the towers (find a permutation) that maximises the needed rope length. Correct?

Comment: Problem statement as is could use a lot of improvement. I think we're trying to find, for an array of positive integers `heights`, `max(abs(heights[i] - heights[j]) + (j - i + 1)), j > i`. Looks like the main trick is to keep track of local peaks/extremes to the left/right of the global minimum and maximum, which is definitely doable in quasilinear time and probably doable in linear time if we're clever.